# JavaScript date() - for date-time clock

Tags: javascript, php

To show a Clock on the WordPress website, I'm using a simple code suggested at the following link:

- [**JavaScript Clock**](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/clock.php) — plus2net.com

I changed the display function to:

```
function display_ct() {
    var strcount
    var now = new Date();
    var d = Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds() );
    // obtain local UTC offset and convert to msec
    localOffset = now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    var c = new Date(d + localOffset);
    document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = c;
    tt=display_c();
}
```

So that it's showing:

```
Sun Jul 20 2014 14:57:47 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)
```

The site is a Bangladesh-based site, so I need to show the time to be `GMT+6` always. But I want to format the display like below:

```
Dhaka: Jul 20 2014 02:57:47 PM
```

I know I can show the string `Dhaka:`, but I can't modify the view of the JS to this. I've checked `getFullYear()`, `getMonth()` etc. but each time they are returning single value. How come the large output comes out from the `date()` function then? I din't check my code otherwise Dhaka.

I'm sorry, I'm novice in JavaScripting. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Ngs4v/

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

var date = new Date();

//get mm dd yyyy
var mnth = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
var dt = date.getDate();
var yr = date.getFullYear();

//get hh mm ss
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var hour = date.getHours();

//get AM/PM 
var ampm = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
hour = hour % 12;
hour = hour ? hour : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;

$('#date').text('Dhaka : ' + mnth + ' ' + dt + ' '+ yr + ' ' + hour + ':'+ minutes + ':'+ seconds + ' ' + ampm);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Hope the time is showing correct even outside Bangladesh. (Live site: vendorpact.com)